# Usage of 'commas' vs 'commata'

Tags: word-usage, grammatical-number

I've learned quite recently, that plural form from **comma** is **commata** (but commas is also correct, such as index-indices-indexes). I've learned the rule for [German](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Komma), and I've checked [the English version](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/comma) too.

This is the first time I've consciously seen that word (I could came across it before, but I haven't notice). What is the usage of that 2 plural forms? Which is more recent in professional literature (for blogs/twitter&co I'd guess, 'commas')?

Should I, as non-native speaker, making many common mistakes, use such 'finesse' plural forms, or it sounds funny in such context?

Comment: I have never seen commata in the wild - http://goo.gl/FFj7oh

Comment: I have, but only in their natural habitat, i.e. Greece. Where people would mean "parties" as in political organisations.

Comment: I would imagine that "commata" is used in English at most in technical jargon.  But the *OED* does not even list that.  I did find that "commata" is a programming language designed for golfing ... https://github.com/totallyhuman/commata

Comment: The OED does have "commata": *comma, n. -- Forms:  Plural commas (formerly -aes); as Latin or Greek, commata /ˈkɒmətə/. It also appears in MW unabridged (paywalled.)

Comment: I enjoy writing *commata* when speaking for myself, but have not dared to do so in (e.g.) a Wikipedia article.

Answer (score 14):

Use *commas*, not *commata*. The latter is simply not used by native speakers.

Take a look, for example, at [Google's Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=commas%2C+commata&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccommas%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccommata%3B%2Cc0) on *commas* versus *commata*:

[image: Google's Ngram Viewer on *commas* versus *commata*]

It's not even close.

Comment: Righty-o, make sure you have a very long pole if you are trying to touch it. :)